# Change style of all of one HTML element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can apply an opacity to all divs with some simple CSS:

```
div {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But, how can I change the opacity of all divs dynamically using Javascript?

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = 0.5;
```

Predictably so, as this targets elements with an ID...

Is there a way, using Javascript, that I can edit the style applied to all divs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select all div by `querySelectorAll` and then loop.

```js
function changeOpacity(){
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
  divs.forEach(function(elem){
    elem.style.opacity = 0.5;
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
Niklesh
</div>
<div>
Raut
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="changeOpacity()" value="Change Opacity">
```

Comment: I can't use classes for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @CasparB : Then use `querySelectorAll` and loop to apply opacity in all div element

Comment: This returns an error message of `Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined`

Comment: @CasparB : I changed my answer , now it works without error.

Comment: For this, you need a div with in ID - is there no way to do the same without using any ID's?

Comment: @CasparB : remove id , there is no need its just optional to select within specific section

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) can get you a list of elements which share a tag name. You can then loop over it like an array.

A better bet would be to predefine your styles in CSS using a class on the body and a descendant selector, and then toggle that class with JavaScript.

```
div { opacity: 1; }
body.foo div { opacity: 0.5; }
```

and

```
document.body.classList.add("foo");
```

Comment: Thank you. getElementsByTagName was just what I was looking for. Cheers!

Caspar

Comment: @CasparB — I said "You can then loop over it like an array" … and you aren't.

Comment: Missed it, sorry